# UITestActionLog is empty after long running codedui tests

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Does anyone know anything about the UITestActionLog.html file ending up empty for long running test.

When I run just a few steps I get the file just fine with the expected content.
When I run my full test a bit over two hours the file ends up with just 28kb but with virtually no content. It just has this in it "Coded UI Test Log" on the top-left and "TOTAL TIME:" on the top-right.

I could not find anything about it on the web. 
I am wondering if someone else has had this issue and what could be tweaked to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: Same issue here...getting CodedUITestInvoker out of memory error but test has completed and html is empty...seems like it happening for long tests

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the images captured are too large when you have:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.LoggerOverrideState = HtmlLoggerState.AllActionSnapshot;
```

We changed that parameter to:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.LoggerOverrideState = HtmlLoggerState.ErrorAndWarningOnlySnapshot;
```

We don't have screenshots anymore but we have the details of the steps (i.e. the HTMl file is still generated)!

Next I will looks at the System.Drawing to see if we can't override the default screenshot size and encoding, this way we can restore the AllActionSnapshot but with lower resolution of screenshots....to be continued!

Comment: Thanks. Yes I ended up modifying the screenshot size.

Comment: I actually logged a bug about this at Microsoft and they acknowledge it. We were hitting a max buffer size ...I can't find the exact detail anymore but they said it was to be fixed in 2015 version.

Comment: @RamonAldana How did you manage to change the screenshot size on CodedUI?

Comment: We didn't...wasn't able to achieve that. It's probably possible but didn't invest time in that.